# Cluetip not closing on mouseout event

Tags: jquery, cluetip

I was trying to use [cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#options) to help my clients to notify new features added to the app. First, it will a show '?' icon when user hovers a new link and then a cluetip will display when user hover that '?' icon.

Everything works fine except in one case, when mouse pointer moves back to the link after displaying cluetip it throws "b.data("cluetip") is undefined error"  and cluetip will not close and onHide event will not fire at that time.

what might be the problem?

thanks

Comment: Could you please share the html & code you are using to make cluetip work. I demo on jsfiddle.net would be best!

Comment: Got solution from [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/content/cluetip-doesnt-close-mouseout). Thanks fudgey.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://plugins.jquery.com/content/cluetip-doesnt-close-mouseout for the answer.